# array of pointers to array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

we can declare array of strings the following way:

```
char *words[] = { "abc", "def", "bad", "hello", "captain", "def", "abc", "goodbye" };
```

Now I have an existing array of strings suppose:

```
   char strings[4][20];
   strcpy(strings[0], "foo");
   strcpy(strings[1], "def");
   strcpy(strings[2], "bad");
   strcpy(strings[3], "hello");
```

I want to do something like this:

```
   char *words[4];
   for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
   {
      words[j] = &strings[j];
   }
```

So that words would have the same structure as if I have defined it as in the beginning. Do you guys know how to do that?

Comment: What would be `hosts` in this context?

Comment: What is the actual issue you are trying to solve? How the compiler lays it out "in the beginning" is probably a single chunk of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *words[] = { "abc", "def", "bad", "hello", "captain", "def", "abc", "goodbye" };
```

And

```
char *words[8];
words[0] = "abc";
words[1] = "def";
words[2] = "bad";
words[3] = "hello";
words[4] = "captain";
words[5] = "def";
words[6] = "abc";
words[7] = "goodbye";
```

Are the same things.

In both cases `words` is an array of pointers to chars. In C, strings are pointers to chars, literally. Same thing.

```
char *a[] = { "abc", "def", "bad", "hello", "captain", "def", "abc", "goodbye" };
char *b[8];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    b[i] = a[i];
```

Should work just fine too.

You only have to keep in mind that those are **string literals**, so they are read only. It's not some buffer you can modify.

And even if you use buffers, theres another point to observe:

```
char a[4][20];
char *b[4];
int i;

strcpy(a[0], "foo");
strcpy(a[1], "def");
strcpy(a[2], "bad");
strcpy(a[3], "hello");

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    b[i] = a[i];

strcpy(b[0], "not foo");

printf("%s", a[0]);
// prints "not foo"
```

By modifying a string in `b` you modified the string in `a` aswell, because when you do `b[i] = a[i]` you are not copying the string, only the pointer, the memory address where its stored.

Comment: ye, but i have `char a[8][20];` and `char * b[8]`. When I tried that it gives segmentation fault

Comment: In this context you cannot copy from `b` to `a` because the pointers in `a` cannot be modified. `a` is a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

No need for the address of:

```
char *words[4];
for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
   words[j] = strings[j];
}
```

Comment: It may be useful to note that another way of writing this is `words[j] = &strings[i][0];` - the pointers are to the first character of the arrays that contain strings, not to the arrays themselves.